# Problems with SAS DDE with Office 2010

Tags: sas

When I was running office 2007, my SAS DDE script populated, saved and closed the excel file just fine.

I recently updated to office 2010 and the population works fine...but excel stops at the save dialog box. I have to manually click on Save which I did not have to do before.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Codes I am using:

```
filename commands DDE 'EXCEL|SYSTEM';
data _null_;
file commands;
put '[OPEN("pathtoexcelfile.xls")]';
run;

data _null_;
file commands;
put "[Save.as(""&saveas_Path.&saveas..xls"")]";
put "[Close]";
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `(0)` to your close statement.  This tells it not to prompt.

```
data _null_;
file commands;
put "[Save.as(""&saveas_Path.&saveas..xls"")]";
put "[Close(0)]";
run;
```

This is my full macro (explains some of the doc type parameters):

```
/******************************************************************************
** PROGRAM:  MACRO.DDE_SAVE_AS.SAS
**
** DESCRIPTION: SAVES THE CURRENT EXCEL FILE.  IF THE FILE
**              ALREADY EXISTS IT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN.
**
** PARAMETERS: iSAVEAS: THE DESTINATION FILENAME TO SAVE TO.
**             iType  : (OPTIONAL. DEFAULT=BLANK). 
**                      BLANK = XL DEFAULT SAVE TYPE
**                          1 = XLS DOC - OLD SCHOOL! PRE OFFICE 2007?
**                         44 = HTML - PRETTY COOL! CHECK IT OUT... 
**                         51 = XLSX DOC - OFFICE 2007 ONWARDS COMPATIBLE?
**                         57 = PDF
** 
** NOTES:  IF YOU ARE GETTING A DDE ERROR WHEN RUNNING THIS MACRO THEN DOUBLE
**         CHECK YOU HAVE PERMISSIONS TO SAVE WHERE YOU ARE TRYING TO SAVE THE
**         FILE.
** 
*******************************************************************************
** VERSION:
** 1.0 ON: 01APR10 BY: RP
**     CREATED.  
******************************************************************************/

%macro dde_save_as(iSaveAs=,iType=);
  %local iDocTypeClause;

  %let iDocTypeClause=;
  %if "&iType" ne "" %then %do;
    %let iDocTypeClause=,&iType;
  %end;

  filename cmdexcel dde 'excel|system';
  data _null_;
    file cmdexcel;
    put '[error(false)]';
    put "%str([save.as(%"&iSaveAs%"&iDocTypeClause)])";
    put '[error(true)]';
  run;
  filename cmdexcel clear;

%mend;
/*%dde_save_as(iSaveAs=d:\rrobxltest, iType=44);*/
```

Comment: Hi i come to dde issue today. what if i want to close the excel file without save it? close(0) seems not work.

Comment: @useR `close(0)` does work.  This code will do it: `filename cmdexcel dde 'excel|system';
  data _null_;
    file cmdexcel;
    put '[close(0)]';
  run;
  filename cmdexcel clear;`

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following before:

```
put '[save.as("' "&savepath\&savename..&save_ext" '",1,,false,,false)]';
```

I can't say what the parameters "1" and "false" achieve as I haven't got the DDE documentation to hand and can't find it online (it's called macrofun.hlp and you'll find references to it in many SUGI papers, e.g. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p011-26.pdf)

In any case, it might be worth investigating alternatives to DDE which is fairly old at this stage.