# SAS DDE to Excel 2016 fix/ alternative?

Tags: excel, sas, excel-2016, dde

I'm relatively new to SAS programming and have inherited a code that has been written with DDE to open and export data to a template.

Below is the code used :

```
** Use DDE to port the data to Excel template.;
* Start Excel.;

OPTIONS NOXWAIT NOXSYNC;

X "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE'";

DATA _NULL_;
   zzzz = sleep(20);
RUN;

* Open the Excel file.;

FILENAME CMDEXCEL DDE 'EXCEL|SYSTEM';

DATA _NULL_;
   FILE CMDEXCEL;
    PUT '[OPEN("I:\J3 O\J3 OP Integration Division\Customer Support\RESEARCH\Weekly Workload\Open Ticket SAS Reports\Open_detail_Template.xlsx")]';
RUN;

DATA _NULL_;
   zzzz = sleep(20);
RUN;


* Move labels.;

FILENAME DDEWRITE DDE "EXCEL|Open!r2c1:r7000c14" NOTAB;

DATA _NULL_;
   FILE DDEWRITE;
   set todays_detail;
    if crm_group = 'OP';
   put
       color '09'x
       employee '09'x
       ticket_number '09'x
       pri_text '09'x
       open_date '09'x
       due_date '09'x
       classification '09'x
       requisition_num '09'x
       nsn '09'x
       dodaac '09'x
       depot '09'x
       status '09'x
       tot_tix '09'x
       tot_actions
   ;
run;

DATA _NULL_;
   zzzz = sleep(2);
RUN;



DATA _NULL_;
   FILE CMDEXCEL;
  PUT '[SAVE.as("'"I:\J3 O\J3 OP Integration Division\Customer Support\RESEARCH\Weekly Workload\Open Ticket SAS Reports\Open Ticket Detail Report &rpt_date2..xlsx"'")]';
  PUT '[QUIT()]';
run;
```

What Ive noticed is that the X statement opens up the excel app fine. However that is where it gets hung up. On my colleagues computers, the template opens up and you can see the data being written into the appropriate template fields. I have tried many different things to try to get the DDE connection to work. Ive tried to disable all add ins, disable and enable the ignore other applications check box in excel, closed all apps and only run SAS EG, Restart my computer and run it etc etc.

i have also looked into the answers from

[SAS put data to Excel via DDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266439/sas-put-data-to-excel-via-dde)

[Problems with SAS DDE with Office 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198071/problems-with-sas-dde-with-office-2010)

[Change from DDE to proc export because office 2016 does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802741/change-from-dde-to-proc-export-because-office-2016-does-not-support-it)

The last link i think is the most helpful but i would like to try to keep the code as is.

I do have the SAS PC/ACCESS license so i was thinking proc import and proc export might be an option. Im not quite sure how i would replicate it to do the same steps as the DDE code.

Thank you for the help. I greatly appreciate the time.

Note: I have read an option to repair microsoft works, however at the moment this is not an option i can take.

Comment: Does Excel have DDE enabled as an option? It may open (system command) but may not accept DDE commands if that isn't enabled. And you need to provide more information on where it's going wrong and if there's an error with SAS.

Comment: @Reeza Where would i find that setting? Is that the same setting under the options-advanced-general- ignore applications using DDE? The error occurs during the : DATA _NULL_;
   FILE CMDEXCEL;
    PUT '[OPEN("I:\J3 O\J3 OP Integration Division\Customer Support\RESEARCH\Weekly Workload\Open Ticket SAS Reports\Open_detail_Template.xlsx")]';. Excel opens up fine but the template does not open at all. It hangs there until i kill SAS in the task manager.

Comment: No, it's in the Trust Center, see instructions about halfway down this page. You likely need both options set though. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/block-or-unblock-external-content-in-office-documents-10204ae0-0621-411f-b0d6-575b0847a795

Comment: @Reeza I took a look at the page. I enabled the first part of the settings, interesting enough the DDE portion is missing. Any ideas of why that may be the case?

Comment: Are you using Office 365, 2016, 2010?

Comment: DDE was disabled in December 2017 by Microsoft due to security concerns. It's possible it was entirely removed from Excel by your org but that seems weird.

Comment: I tested your code, works fine on my system (office 2016) with 'Ignore option' off of course. Note that you have a pause of 20 seconds there so I'm assuming you're waiting the 20 seconds to see if the data appears too.

Comment: @Reeza I am utilizing Excel 2016. My other colleagues have the same version and everything works well.

Comment: I checked Excel 2016 and mine doesn't have it either, but it does work anyway. DDE does work to some degree because the file is opened, so the connection string is the issue somehow. This is the exact code being run? The only other thing to check is trust center to ensure the file is trusted. If it opens and you have a popup or yellow header that says you can't print or edit the file that's why.

Comment: @Reeza The pause is there so that excel can open up and load properly before asking it to open my template. Once the 20 seconds are up, on my colleagues computers i can see SAS pasting all the values under the headings and then saving and closing

Comment: @ Reeza Yes this is the exact code being run. I will take a look at the template and see if i get the yellow warning

Comment: Just run up to the open file part and then see if you can print or edit the document.

Comment: @Reeza So i ran all the code up to this portion: OPTIONS NOXWAIT XSYNC;

X "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE'"; This opens excel but it keeps it hung up until i click out of excel. Once i click exit on excel, the SAS program finishes up and give me the log.

Comment: Did you add the location to trusted locations?

Comment: @Reeza Unfortunately my Org disabled that feature. However, it should be trusted because the trust documents in network is clicked on.

Comment: Sorry dude, out of ideas. It's clearly something very specific to your machine.

Comment: @Reeza No problem. Thanks for the help. I will attempt to rewrite it using proc import and proc export and see if i get any results. Again much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DDE is ancient technology.  There are some strange interactions with other processes on your PC that can make it break.  You might get it to work if you can figure out what other program you are running that is hijacking the DDE signals and close it.

Or switch to another method. Such as Visual Basic.

Take a look at this paper. See example 8 for something close to your situation.

http://www.sascommunity.org/mwiki/images/d/d6/2444-2018.pdf

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will read it and add it to my code and see how it goes. I will give up on the whole DDE method. I have tried for days with no luck on identifying which app is hijacking the signal.

Comment: Just an update. I read the document and tried to run the macro. Looks like i am getting access denied when the code runs CMD prompt for the VBScript. Very useful answer nonetheless